# Current syntax error when connecting to version 5.0 mysql

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I am really having a tough time understanding what syntax to use. I am VERY green when it comes to coding. I copied this code from another website that is working just fine but they are hooked up to a 4.3 version of mysql- can anyone help?This is the error-

> **Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1, city, state, zip, ) VALUES ('', , ' 1', '', '', '','' )' at line 1**

```
Here is my code:

mysql_select_db("membership70", $con);  

$name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Name']); 
$address1=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Address1']); 
$city=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city']); 
$state=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['state']); 
$zip=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['zip']);
$email=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

$sql="INSERT INTO Members (name, email, adress 1, city, state, zip, ) VALUES ('$name', , '$address 1', '$city', '$state', '$zip','$email' )"; 

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Also, on this site you can vote up answers you find useful, or even accept them if they solve your problem. - Just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

You have speces in `address [space] 1` both places.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Members (name, email, adress 1, city, state, zip, ) VALUES ('$name', , '$address 1', '$city', '$state', '$zip','$email' )";
```

Also you have an extra colon after `zip` and the order of the values does not match the order you gave the column names. Try:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Members (name, email, adress1, city, state, zip) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$address1', '$city', '$state', '$zip')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a column `adress 1` there, that's not a valid column name in mysql and it could not have worked on any mysql version. What columns does your table have?

Also, your second value is empty, put some value in there (or a default one). And a comma at the end of the columns list. Email at the wrong place.

Maybe this would work?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Members (name, email, adress1, city, state, zip) ".
       "VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$address1', '$city', '$state', '$zip')";
```

(I'm not sure about the third column, should it spell `address1`?)

Comment: @Darci, mission accomplished! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the space in adress 1 and your variable $adress 1....not allowed (spaces that is)

Answer (score 0):

That statement clearly tells you the SQL syntax is broken. Take a closer look into your statement in the $sql variable. echo it to debug it properly.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO .....";
echo $sql; die();
```

At first glace, there shouldn't be a blank neither the column adress nor the corresponding php variable. And you should sort the order of your columns. email is declare second, so don't put the value of it at the end.

So, instead of...

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Members (name, email, adress 1, city, state, zip, ) VALUES ('$name', , '$address 1', '$city', '$state', '$zip','$email' )";
```

...try...

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Members (name, email, adress1, city, state, zip) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$address1', '$city', '$state', '$zip' )";
```

Comment: ok- did that- now it says Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/content/91/7551591/html/verify.php on line 28

Comment: Again, try echoing your SQL statement like mentioned above. Unexpected T_STRING might be a syntax error (not properly closed string etc.), but without any more informations about your code there's way too much guessing involved.